# Javascript dynamic consecutive ID within a loop in relation to the number of times it appears th in html

Tags: javascript, dynamic, datatables, filtering

I am using "datatables" and I want to loop I automatically generate IDs based on the number of "th" that appear in the document to avoid writing:

```
$("#col1_filter").keyup(function() { fnFilterColumn(0) } ); 
$("#col1_regex").click(function() { fnFilterColumn(0) } ); 
$("#col1_smart").click(function() { fnFilterColumn(0) } ) ;
```

for each generated HTML document.

The original information here:
http://datatables.net/examples/api/regex.html

I'm trying with this code but there is always the last value:

```
$(document).ready(function() {     
    $("#global_filter").keyup( fnFilterGlobal );
    $("#global_regex").click( fnFilterGlobal );
    $("#global_smart").click( fnFilterGlobal );

    var dt = $(".table thead th").length;
    alert(dt);
    var j; 
    var w;
    for (var i=0;i<dt;++i)
    {
    j=i;
    k= j+1; 
    alert(j);
    alert(k);
    $("#col"+k+"_filter").keyup(function() { fnFilterColumn(j) } ); 
    $("#col"+k+"_regex").click(function() { fnFilterColumn(j) } ); 
    $("#col"+k+"_smart").click(function() { fnFilterColumn(j) } ) ;
    } 
} );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a local copy of `j`, otherwise you are working with a shared copy (that is, `fnFilterColumn(j)` refers to the same version of `j` that you are updating in each iteration).  To do this, you have to create a closure around `j` (or call it `i`, it doesn't matter):

```
for (var i=0;i<dt;++i)
{
    (function(j) {
        var k= j+1; 
        alert(j);
        alert(k);
        $("#col"+k+"_filter").keyup(function() { fnFilterColumn(j) } ); 
        $("#col"+k+"_regex").click(function() { fnFilterColumn(j) } ); 
        $("#col"+k+"_smart").click(function() { fnFilterColumn(j) } ) ;
    })(i);
}
```

[Here's](http://jsfiddle.net/k2j55/7/) a simplified Fiddle that illustrates the difference.